# log4net rolling file appender not working

Tags: asp.net, log4net

I have following configuration:

```
<log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="All"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </root>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="mylog.log"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
      <datePattern value=".yyyyMMdd"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="5MB"/>
      <countDirection value="1"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

And the following code in global.asax:

```
Sub Application_Start()
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)

        BasicConfigurator.Configure();

        LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Global_asax)).Error("Logger configured")


    End Sub
```

For the tag file in configuration above. I have tried C:\my folder\mylog.log as well as what is seen above mylog.log

However, I do not see this file generated anywhere and there are no exceptions.

Environment: VS 2013 ASP.Net VB. Running via Debug menu. When I run IISExpress is started by VS2013 and site runs. but no log is seen.

I have tried various combinations for the file tag but nothing works.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This used to work for me (I've switched to the lighter and better configurable NLog), log rolled daily, was written in a subfolder named "Logs" under the app's path.

```
  <appender name="RollingDebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Logs\" />
    <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd'-FULL.log'" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="100" />
    <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is final version of what I ended up doing that worked:

```
 <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </root>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="logs\log4net.log"/>
      <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd'-FULL.log'" />
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>      
      <maximumFileSize value="250KB"/>      
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

And

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure()
LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Global_asax)).Error("Logger configured")
```

This logged to log\log4net.log in the application directory (i.e. where my code is )

Comment: Missing XmlConfigurator.Configure() call in my case. Thx!

Answer (score 4):

You should turn on log4net's internal debugging to figure out what's failing...

Sample web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="textWriterTraceListener"
             type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="C:\log4net_internal.log"/>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

More information available [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html) on the troubleshooting section.

Comment: Important!  In my rolling file appender file path I had `${LOCALAPPDATA}\My\Relative\Path.myapp.log`.  Using a path like that for the intializeData attribute did not work.  I needed something like mentioned in the answer, it didn't work with `${LOCALAPPDATA}`

Comment: And Log4net, in their infinite wisdom throw no exception when the diagnostic file doesn't write due to permissions.  How wonderful!  So they swallow the exception for not being able to diagnose!!!  UGGHHHHH!!!!!!

Comment: That’s normal, Log4net works in a way so as to cause as little influence as possible in your program. It does not cause exceptions, slow downs, and other unexpected behaviors. The only way to get to figure out what’s it doing is through the internal debugging, and that should only be enabled for development purposes. Don’t deploy the internal debugging to your development/quality/production  servers.

Comment: Is there an internal debugging different from the diagnostic tool?  I'm just confused as to why a tool to diagnose why something doesn't work also swallows exceptions.  That makes it even harder to diagnose.

Comment: Nope, you only have the internal debugging to figure out what's wrong... According to the [FAQ](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html)  `log4net will not throw unexpected exceptions at run-time potentially causing your application to crash.... Uncaught exceptions are handled as serious bugs requiring immediate attention.`

Answer (score 0):

*_%date{yyyyMMdd}.log

below is the key, if this is missing u will see logs like above

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="textWriterTraceListener"
             type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="C:\log4net_internal.log"/>
 **<staticLogFileName value="false" />**
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be an issue with the log folder permissions. Without granting `Modify` permissions to the process user, log4net does not create a rolling log file.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Adding debug = "true" to the `<log4net>` tag (i.e. `<log4net debug="true">` ) can help to solve the problem